synchronize user's management between my database and keycloak with nest js postres and angular
I am working on an application with nest js in backend and angular in frontend, and i should use keycloak in a way that users can be inserted automatically from the form of my application as well as i the login procedures should be through the personalized form of my app not the keycloak form. if  this is possible i want to know how can i configure the frontend and the backend.
I tried to configure keycloak and initialized it   in the app.module of the front end to show me my login form page but it returned undefined document in the navigator.
that's app.module.ts:
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';

function initializeKeycloak(authService: AuthService): () => Promise<void> {
  return () => authService.init();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      deps: [AuthService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}


and this is auth.service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private keycloakService: KeycloakService) {}

  async init(): Promise<void> {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      await this.keycloakService.init({
        config: {
          url: 'http://localhost:8080',
          realm: 'grc',
          clientId: 'grc-client-id',
        },
        initOptions: {
          onLoad: 'login-required',
        },
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Not running in a browser environment');
    }
  }
}


